# Visualize Neural Net Layers in Torch, without itorch

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch, conv-neural-network

I have a neural net with several convolution layers and I'd like to visualize the feature maps I'm creating.

I've seen this post:
[Visualize images in intermediate layers in torch (lua)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509912/visualize-images-in-intermediate-layers-in-torch-lua)

which suggests using itorch, but it requires running my code in an itorch notebook which I would like to avoid.

Are there any other Torch packages which can be used to visualize convolution layers?

EDIT (with detailed solution):

Since I found so few resources online about how to go about doing this I documented my full solution and slapped it on Github. Anyone who wants to visualize neural nets in torch can just go here to get started!

https://github.com/egaebel/torch-neural-network-visualization

Much thanks again to YuTse for the gnuplot tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[gnuplot](https://github.com/torch/gnuplot)

in itorch console mode(`itorch`) / torch mode(`th`)

```
require 'image';

a = image.lena();

require 'gnuplot';

gnuplot.figure(1);

gnuplot.imagesc(a[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I haven't gotten back to this project yet, I'll probably give it a try this weekend!

Comment: Will this only work in itorch? I'd like to be able to use regular torch.

Comment: You can also use `qlua`, the `image` package works very well with it.